# Confused over passive-voice - future simple or future continuous?

Tags: passive-voice, future-tense, exam-questions

> 1. The book report will be given by Mary to the class.
>    Reconstruct the sentence in the passive form.
>    a) Mary will be giving a book report to the class.
>    b) Mary will give a book report to the class.

Which one would you choose? The passive form is (be)+past participle but to me a) also sounds correct?

Comment: You've got things mixed up. The original sentence is *already* in a passive-voice  construction. Meanwhile, the two rephrased versions are active-voice constructions.

Comment: Neither a) nor b) are written in the passive voice. The original sentence is in the passive, you cannot rewrite a sentence in the passive if it's already in that voice.